# Error while trying to query the in memory database with Persist Client

Tags: ballerina, persist

I am getting the following error when tried to run the code which uses bal persist for inmemory database access(version: Ballerina 2201.6.0 (Swan Lake Update 6)

```
Language specification 2022R4 Update Tool 1.3.15) 
 Compiling source
        user/rainier:0.1.0
ballerinax/persist.inmemory:1.0.0 [central.ballerina.io ->/Users/user/.ballerina/repositories/central.ballerina.io/bala/ballerinax/persist.inmemory/1.0.0]  100% [==================] 20/20 KB (0:00:00 / 0:00:00) 
        ballerinax/persist.inmemory:1.0.0 pulled from central successfully
ERROR [generated/store/persist_client.bal:(29:5,32:16)] {ballerina/jballerina.java}CLASS_NOT_FOUND 'io.ballerina.stdlib.persist.inmemory.datastore.InMemoryProcessor'
ERROR [generated/store/persist_client.bal:(34:5,37:16)] {ballerina/jballerina.java}CLASS_NOT_FOUND 'io.ballerina.stdlib.persist.inmemory.datastore.InMemoryProcessor'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be caused by the absence of native dependancy in the ballerina.toml file, which was added during the `bal persist init`. Can you check whether following dependency in your Ballerina.toml file

```
[[platform.java11.dependency]]
groupId = "io.ballerina.stdlib"
artifactId = "persist.inmemory-native"
version = "1.0.0"
```